# Inserting in vector of vector when sizes are not known?

Tags: c++, vector

What would be the right way to handle a scenario when you want to return a `vector<vector<int>>` say named as triplets `vector<vector<int>> triplets;`. There are two possible returns involved. First, when nothing is populated in triplets as condition to populate it was never satisfied. Second depending on a scenario it is populated with vector having 3 elements.

```
if(nums[left_index]+nums[i]+nums[right_index] == 0)
                    {
                        triplets[total_count].push_back(nums[left_index]);
                        triplets[total_count].push_back(nums[i]);
                        triplets[total_count].push_back(nums[right_index]);
                        ++total_count;
                    }
```

Above is a scenario taken from code posted below.

```
    class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<int>> threeSum(vector<int>& nums) {
        int total_size=nums.size();
        vector<vector<int>> triplets;
        if(total_size<3)
        {
            triplets;
        }
        
        std::sort(nums.begin(),nums.end());
        int total_count = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i<total_size-1;++i)
        {
            
            int right_index = i+1;
            int left_index = 0;
            std::cout << i <<" " <<left_index <<" " << right_index <<"\n";
            while(right_index <= total_size-1)
            {
                while(left_index < i)
                {
                    std::cout << i <<" " <<left_index <<" " << right_index <<"\n";
                    std::cout <<"Sums is:" << nums[left_index]+nums[i]+nums[right_index] <<"\n";
                    if(nums[left_index]+nums[i]+nums[right_index] > 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    if(nums[left_index]+nums[i]+nums[right_index] == 0)
                    {
                        triplets[total_count].push_back(nums[left_index]);
                        triplets[total_count].push_back(nums[i]);
                        triplets[total_count].push_back(nums[right_index]);
                        ++total_count;
                    }
                    left_index++;
                }
                ++right_index;
            }
        }
        return triplets;
    }
};
```

The error that I receive while running my code is :

```
Line 1034: Char 9: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>' (stl_vector.h)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1043:9
```

Is it possible to create a reserve for such scenarios when vector of vector is involved. How would reserve be done for inner and outer vector ?

Comment: @Invictus `class Solution {` That means leetcode I think? To be honest I wouldn't be surprised to learn that some people downvote just for that.

Comment: Downvote might be related to the fact this is clearly a "competitive coding" excercise, and not a strict question about C++ (the language).  The code for competitive coding solutions is often hard to read and/or it is clear bad C++ programming habits have crept in. Like hard to read code with unclear variable names and missing small functions (with clear names). So yes Leetcode has a kind of a bad reputation here

Comment: The advise we often give is to first learn C++, so you will also can better interpret the error messages you are seeing and why.

Comment: So good sources to learn cpp from are : A [recent C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) or have a go at https://www.learncpp.com/ (that's pretty decent, and pretty up-to-date).
 For C++ reference material use : [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/). And after you learned the C++ basics from those sources, look at the [C++ coreguidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) regularely to keep up-to-date with the latest guidelines.

Comment: @Invictus Since this is leetcode, you should post a `main` program with the test case that fails, and the `main` simply creating an instance of `Solution` with the test data.  Your error is a runtime error, and missing these details could cause downvotes to occur.  Another reason for leetcode downvotes many times is a lack of debugging, and explicitly because Leetcode gives the failing test cases to the participant, but the participant fails to do any debugging.  Not saying you are guilty of this, but just to let you know what can cause a downvote on Leetcode-ish questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `triplets` vector has a size of zero when you try to assign triplets to it. You understood that you need to use `push_back` on the second dimension of your 2D vector, but forgot that the first dimension also needs `push_back`.

There's a few different ways you could handle this, I'd perhaps go with something like this

```
triplets.push_back(std::vector<int>(3, 0)); // add a triplet of zeros
triplets.back()[0] = nums[left_index];      // assign to the triplet just added
triplets.back()[1] = nums[i];
triplets.back()[2] = nums[right_index];
```

Also it seems that

```
if(total_size<3)
{
    triplets;
}
```

should be

```
if(total_size<3)
{
    return triplets;
}
```